# Gatefold or inward fold layout

Tags: packages, margins, templates, layout

Would someone have an elegant way to render an inward fold or gatefold card? I can't seem to find anything/package on the subject, there is the gcard package, but it does offer this option.

Here is an illustration of such a fold.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

edit, context: An invitation card which would include the text in the middle square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ideas, one based on `minipage` and the other on `tabular`. Both of these effectively use 1/4 of the textwidth, then 1/2 the textwidth, then 1/4 of the textwidth, with possible adjustments to leave space between the three components.

```
% gatefoldprob.tex  SE 594176
%\documentclass[landscape]{article} % PDF output not printed as landscape on my PC
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}
LEFT TEXT FILLING SOME SPACE
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
CENTER TEXT FILLING A LOT MORE SPACE
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}
RIGHT TEXT FILLING SOME SP
\end{minipage}
\newpage
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.21\textwidth}|p{0.43\textwidth}|p{0.21\textwidth}|}
LEFT TEXT FILLING SOME SPACE & 
\vspace{2cm}CENTER TEXT FILLING A LOT MORE SPACE & 
RIGHT TEXT FILLING SOME SPACE\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the `tabular` code I have included vertical lines showing the interface between the three columns.

I have no idea what you might want to put on the three "columns" of your gatecards. In any event if you use any of the above you will have to consider the location of the columns and how to put text in your desired (vertical) locations.

Following your question's edit I have extended my MWE to show how you could put an invitation on the center of the gatefold.

```
% gatefoldprob.tex  SE 594176
%\documentclass[landscape]{article} % PDF output not printed as landscape on my PC
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}
\vfill
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}
LEFT TEXT FILLING SOME SPACE
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
%\vfill
CENTER TEXT FILLING A LOT MORE SPACE
%\vfill
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}
RIGHT TEXT FILLING SOME SP
\end{minipage}
\vfill
\mbox{}

\newpage
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.21\textwidth}|p{0.43\textwidth}|p{0.21\textwidth}|}
LEFT TEXT FILLING SOME SPACE & 
\vspace{2cm}CENTER TEXT FILLING A LOT MORE SPACE & 
RIGHT TEXT FILLING SOME SPACE\\
\end{tabular}

\newpage

\mbox{}
\vfill
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}
LEFT TEXT?
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
%\vfill
%CENTER TEXT FILLING A LOT MORE SPACE
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
Dear Joe and Jacqui,

We sincerely hope that you will be able to attend Josephine's
coming of age party on 1 April 2027.

With best wishes, Jack \& Joan

RSVP
%\vfill
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.23\textwidth}
RIGHT TEXT?
\end{minipage}
\vfill
\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I thought that you might try something like this yourself. --- GOM

Comment: Thanks, II was wondering if there was a more advanced way, since when printing, this will not take into account the margins etc. The goal was really to have a square in the middle like if you fold an a4 paper landsacpe.

Comment: If you use my `minipage` suggestion but include `mbox{}\vfill` at the start and `\vfill\mbox{}` at the end  then you will get three minipages the height of the page. It is up to you to provide the code for margins, etc., although I have indicated what might be done in that direction by specifying the width of the minipages whach leads to the margins between them via the use of the `\hfil` macro.

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide any context so the best I can do is to give you a start. Of course there are many things that one could add.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\tikzfading[name=lfade,
left color=transparent!100, right color=transparent!80,middle
color=transparent!100]
\definecolor{page}{RGB}{248,245,222}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1][]{enhanced,colback=page, boxrule=0pt,
    sharp corners,
    overlay={
    \path (frame.north west) -- coordinate[pos=0.25] (aux1)
         coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux2)
         coordinate[pos=0.75] (aux3) (frame.north east);
     \fill[gray,path fading=lfade] (frame.south west) rectangle (aux1); 
     \fill[gray,path fading=lfade] (frame.south-|aux2) rectangle (aux3);
     },
    drop lifted shadow,#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}[height=6cm]
 
\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, might have been a misunderstanding. The goal is to write some text in the inner middle square. The illustration was to explain the layout. Still quite impressed by your mastery of Tikz to pull out the exact same picture with tikz code!